# Can't find "Background" in System Settings

Tags: unity, 14.10, system-settings, desktop-background

Recently I upgraded to 14.10 and afterwards I experienced some problems but slowly I managed to solve most of them. I used GNOME for a while but few days ago I changed back to Unity and today when I wanted to change my background image I noticed that in the system settings there's no such option. It just... disappeared?

Here's another glitch that might be related

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**
Haven't noticed that you don't have the Appearance option.
Try executing these

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-control-center
sudo apt-get install unity-control-center
```

Then, continue with the previous answer.

---

**How to**
There are several ways to change your background image.

1. System settings

From any window, click the top right gear-shaped icon (in your screenshot, it is the icon near vargagaborr), then **System Settings** and move to **Appearance**.

2. Dash
   Click on the dash button (top-left of your screen), type Appearance and click on it.
3. Terminal
   The coolest way to launch your GUI

   `unity-control-center appearance`

---

**Optional**

If you want to configure the unity appearance a little more you can install `ubuntu-tweak`. I think that Ubuntu 14.10 does not have a dedicated ppa, so you have to
download the .deb file from the [official website](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/). Then, to install it, go to the directory where you downloaded the file, open the terminal and execute.

```
sudo dpkg -i ubuntu-tweak_0.8.7-1~trusty2_all.deb 
sudo apt-get install -f
```

The **Tweak** tab contains a lot of useful customization settings you can change.

Comment: Oddly his system settings dont have the section for "Appearance"

Comment: Yeah, haven't noticed that. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Well I don't know how, but Unity Control Center was NOT installed. That surprised me. Now I have the appearance option and I don't have the glitch. Only problem(?) that when I type 'archey' in Terminal it shows that I still use Gnome as my DE.

Comment: I don't know what command you have tried to executed, but the simplest way to show your desktop environment is `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` (should be Unity) and `echo $GDMSESSION` (should be ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively use a program like [WallCH](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/wallch/) (my fav) or [Wally](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/wally/) to manage your desktop background. Both of these apps will allow you to set desktop wallpaper settings like scale, center, stretch, etc, and will override the settings in System Settings > Appearance.

ubuntu-tweak, as suggested by tigerjack89, is also a viable option (and makes managing other aspects like theme, login settings, etc, much easier with its GUI).

I do understand the concern of the Appearance section not even being listed, but unfortunately dont have an answer (never switched out for Gnome). Is your GPU driver / graphics software up to date? If you have an nvidia card, I often find switching to the propietary drivers after a fresh install solves a lot of graphical glitch/artifact issues (as the open source drivers just arent up to par just yet).